# private modifier on inner class

Tags: java, private, inner-classes

Why are we taught that 'private' modifier in Java is only usable before variables and methods declaration, but not for Class, even though we can use 'private' modifier with Nested Classes?

Comment: You should ask this the person teaching you wrong things. Maybe that person stopped learning Java 17 years ago and didn't hear of inner classes.

Answer (score 2):

Someone taught you wrong things. That's not true. Any member of a Class is eligible to have a access modifier. A nested class is also a member of top level class and hence it can have an access modifier.

Always cross check with official docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

> A nested class can be declared private, public, protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be declared public or package private.)